# Globally set C++ source block header arguments

Tags: org-mode, c++

I try to globally set header properties for `C++` source examples, with no success. I would have expected that the following works

```org
 #+PROPERTY: header-args:C++ :var x=1.0
```

What did work is using general header args property:

```org
 #+PROPERTY: header-args :var x=1.1
```

Also specific property drawer worked:

```org
* Resources
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:C++: :var x=1.2
:END:
```

And of course using plain old header arguments works:

```org
#+header: :exports results
#+header: :includes <iostream>
#+header: :var x=1.3
#+begin_src C++
std::cout << x;
#+end_src
```

Could that be a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, that I have to use `cpp` instead of `C++` to get it working:

```org
#+PROPERTY: header-args:cpp :var x=1.0

#+header: :exports results
#+header: :includes <iostream>
#+begin_src cpp
std::cout << x;
#+end_src
```

**Reason:** A single plus behind the property name means: *Append the following property values to the already set ones*. So the line

```org
 #+PROPERTY: header-args:C++ :var x=1.0
```

is interpreted as: Append the value `:var x=1.0` to the value of property `header-args:C+`.